# Modifying the tooltip that appears from the title attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I modify the tooltip that appears from a non-empty title attribute? For example, can I change the font, duration, position, etc.

I've noticed, for example, that Chrome has two different tooltips for the tabs. On mouseover the cross to close the tab, the tooltip appears *below*. On mouseover the title of the tab, the tooltip appears *above*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options for doing this [with](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/how-to-create-link-tooltips-using-css3-and-jquery/) and [without](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-script-free-css3-tooltips/) JS.

Comment: Derek should be clear that the answer is: No, you can't
Then his answer is really helpful.
The attribute Title is standard and quite limited and can't be modified at all. In the case you want to take it further, then you can use other (separate) tools to mimic another type of Tooltip, but you're not using the standard.
As derek says you can seek help in JQuery, and the second link relies in new HTML 5 standard and CSS.

Comment: Ummm, no. My answer was "Yes, you can." It's not something I would bother with, but it can be done. There's nothing "HTML5" about the second link - it's CSS3. The question was asked with tags for javascript, css, and html, so jquery is fair game as well. Can the tooltip appearance be modified with CSS and/or Javascript? Yes, it can with varying degrees of browser compatibility depending on implementation.

Comment: Just look at the question: "Can I modify the tooltip that appears from a non-empty title attribute?" He means the title attribute, can you modify it? And yeah the second link starts with: "We’ve used the HTML5 doctype which is !DOCTYPE html and then called our two stylesheets." So yeah, besides you would need HTML5 for some stuff from CSS3

Comment: "Can I modify the tooltip that appears..." You quoted it yourself. He doesn't ask about modifying the attribute. He asks about modifying the display, which can be done.